# WVGA800 (480x800) & Density ANDROID

Tags: java, android

Table 3 on this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

shows that WVGA800 (480x800) is available with 3 Densities. Does this mean that for each density the game will be loaded with different DPI assets if available ?

But how come same resolution will have different assets or layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Well a certain resolution say 480*800 surely can have different densities....And the assets would be placed in their respective places...Suppose say images for though accomadating as per 480*800 would be placed in different drawables hdpi,mdpi,ldpi... Depending upon your desity type the appropriate drawable would be used automatically...

Though the layout would be same for different densities....But assets and other would vary to give you actuall look and feel..

Hope you would be able to get what I want to convey...

Go through this blog to get a basic understanding for what I mean...

http://wonton-games.blogspot.com/2010/07/tutorial-multiple-screen-support.html

Comment: I already read the blog when searching for an answer but I want to know why supply different assets for the same resolation when the asset is also measured by pixels so...?
Hope you could understand what I mean :D